# Is there any way in vscode to map command `pip install` to `poetry add`?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-poetry

I'm trying to use [python-poetry](https://github.com/sdispater/poetry) as dependency manager for my Python projects. I prefer to use VSCode for my development. However, vscode [doesn't have support](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/1871) for poetry yet, that means any packages installed via vscode are installed using pip.

I wonder if we can tweak vscode settings to map `pip install` to `poetry add` to install packages via poetry?

Comment: Why not run `poetry add` in the built-in terminal?

Comment: Yes. That is doable. There are certain packages like pylint, autopep8 are suggested by vscode and if clicked on vscode get installed automatically. I know we can still install these packages manually but still want to check if there is way to install them automatically as and when vscode suggests.

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't a way to change the installation command.